# exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, maven-2, tomcat7

getting this exception while running tomcat server. I tried with change of -Xms and -Xmx, but no luck.

My project is maven project

my system RAM is 8gb, I have added the "setenv.sh" file in bin folder and given the values like -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m BTW my run command is

> catalina.bat run -config conf/mySchema.xml

```
WARNING: An exception was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Dec 05, 2016 11:16:20 AM org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter log
WARNING: Metadata refreshing has failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Dec 05, 2016 11:18:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Dec 05, 2016 11:18:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: _"I tried with change of -Xms and -Xmx, but no luck."_ What values did ou use? How much memory is installed? How much of that is available?  We cannot help unless you provide details.

Comment: @user75ponic Please do not edit stack traces to use quote formatting.  Stack traces must be formatted as code, not as quotes, to preserve the line breaks, otherwise they become unreadable.

Comment: my system RAM is 8gb, I have added the "setenv.sh" file and give the values like
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m

BTW my run command is catalina.bat run -config conf/myFile.xml

Comment: Your question has a very broad range of answers. Please be specific about your problem, and try to provide as much as details as possible, e.g. what type of app are you running on Tomcat, which specific frameworks are being used (if any) etc.

Comment: Also, @SatishY please do not post details in comments.  [edit] your original post and add the details there.

Comment: my project is maven project

Comment: @JimGarrison
sure, thanks

Comment: Is there any app deployed in this Tomcat or is a brand new one ? If it's a new one, try to restart the setup from scratch because something went wrong there. If you have an app deployed, it's probably the cause of the memory use. If the app takes time before giving you the error, check that the java process is indeed using lots of RAM. If it's not and crashing quickly, it might be a problem in your config. Can you quote here your exact config settings ?

Comment: Hi @EricDarchis
these are the my java_opts
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=320m -XX:MaxNewSize=320m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=31"

Answer (score 1):

Heap space issue comes when you have loaded some heavy file into the JVM while trying to process it. 
For example, if you have loaded a large log file containing up to 1 GB of data, then `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` issue will come.

In case you have a specific requirement where you wish to process large files in Java then try to follow [this link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html)

As it mentions:

### How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

1) An easy way to solve `OutOfMemoryError` in java is to increase the maximum heap size by using JVM options "-Xmx512M", this will immediately solve your OutOfMemoryError. This is my preferred solution when I get OutOfMemoryError in Eclipse, Maven or ANT while building project because based upon size of project you can easily run out of Memory.here is an example of increasing maximum heap size of JVM, Also its better to keep -Xmx to -Xms ration either 1:1 or 1:1.5 if you are setting heap size in your java application

> export JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"

2) The second way to resolve OutOfMemoryError in Java is rather hard and  comes when you don't have much memory and even after increase maximum heap size you are still getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, in this case, you probably want to profile your application and look for any memory leak. You can use Eclipse Memory Analyzer to examine your heap dump or you can use any profiler like Netbeans or JProbe. This is tough solution and requires some time to analyze and find memory leaks.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html#ixzz4RwS3w7ks

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issue. the issue is I have 64 bit OS and 64 bit tomcat 7. But java 7 is 32 bit.

After installing 64 bit java 7 the issue went gone.

thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're calling catalina.bat instead of catalina.sh, so you must put Java options into bin/setenv.bat instead of setenv.sh. If it doesn't exist, try create one, and put this:

```
SET JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score -3):

Add the following line in your manifest.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Kindly check the below code for better understanding.

```
 <application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeq"
    android:largeHeap="true">
```

Comment: Why would an android config parameter have anything to do with Tomcat?

Comment: Same Question..?? tomcat..Android...??...completely separate domains...

Comment: I don't really think that this question is specific to the android SDK.

Comment: You made my day